# Wordpress rest api tag search

Tags: wordpress, tags, wordpress-rest-api

I need to search a list of specific tags, and I found this [docs](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/tags/). List Tags endpoint has a search parameter, but I have no ideas how to use it. Is it for search by one specific tag? Or I can specify several tags like search=tag1+tag2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an example here you can refer to this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180137/retrieving-pages-with-multiple-tags-using-rest-api

As Op has suggested you can try below method to pass the multiple tags

L1 AND L2 AND L3 ; use plus (+)

```
https://example.com/cms/wp-json/pages?filter[tag]=L1+L2+L3
```

L1 OR L2 OR L3 ; use comma (,)

```
https://example.com/cms/wp-json/pages?filter[tag]=L1,L2,L3
```

Comment: Filter has been deprecated: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2799